# How can I merge two Excel spreadsheets with non matching column letters?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have been using Excel for years to compile records of baseball gloves I have repaired. I was assembling an all time mega Excel spreadsheet, and found that in one of the templates I had made, I had the columns listed a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h. But in the second template [how I got two I will never know], I had deleted the second columnn [B], so that spreadsheet reads a,c,d,e,f,g,h etc. The problem is that when I just want to take the entire information from year 2009, and cut and paste it into the newer template, the paste does not work.

Comment: Are "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h" the column letters, or the column-header names?

Comment: What does "the paste does not work" mean exactly? You get an error message? An unexpected result?

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe that it's possible in Excel to delete a column and leave a gap in the column names. 
You have probably *hidden* column B. 
Select columns A and C (by clicking and dragging in the column headers) and right-click;
you should see an `Unhide` option.

Comment: I concur. This is likely the case. +1

Comment: Hiding columns doesn't affect copying and pasting. If the target sheet has a hidden column, cells will still be pasted there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the column in the problem spreadsheet, copying the resulting spreadsheet into your copy buffer and paste it into the spreadsheet without the problem.